# How can I optimize this SQL query? (Solarwinds Orion)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm very new to SQL, and still learning. I'm using a reporting tool called Solarwinds Orion, and I'm honestly not sure how specific the query I have written is to the program, so if there's anything in the query that's confusing, let me know and I'll try to figure out if it's specific to the program or not.

The problem with the query I'm running is that it times out after a very long time (maybe an hour) of running. The database I'm using is huge. Unfortunately I don't really know how huge, but I've been told it's huge.

Is there anything I am doing wrong that would have a huge performance impact?

```
SELECT  TOP 10000
Nodes.Caption                              AS NodeName,
NetflowApplicationSummary.AppName          AS Application_Name,
SUM(NetflowApplicationSummary.TotalBytes)  AS SUM_of_Bytes_Transferred,
AVG(Case OutBandwidth
    When 0 Then 0
    Else (NetflowApplicationSummary.TotalBytes/OutBandwidth) * 100
End)                                       AS TEST_PERCENT

FROM
((NetflowApplicationSummary 
  INNER JOIN Nodes ON (NetflowApplicationSummary.NodeID = Nodes.NodeID)) 
  INNER JOIN InterfaceTraffic ON (Nodes.NodeID = InterfaceTraffic.InterfaceID)) 
  INNER JOIN Interfaces ON (Nodes.NodeID = Interfaces.NodeID)

WHERE
( InterfaceTraffic.DateTime > (GetDate()-30) )
AND
(Nodes.WANCircuit = 1)

GROUP BY Nodes.Caption, NetflowApplicationSummary.AppName
```

EDIT: I ran COUNT() on each of my tables with the below result.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM NetflowApplicationSummary # 50671011
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Nodes                     # 898
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM InterfaceTraffic          # 18000166
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Interfaces                # 3938
                         # Total : 68,676,013
```

I really have no idea if 68 million items is a huge database to be honest.

Comment: Can you check that this join clause is correct? `INNER JOIN InterfaceTraffic ON Nodes.NodeID = InterfaceTraffic.InterfaceID` It looks suspicious that a NodeID is being joind to an InterfaceID.

Comment: Its big but not huge. Have you run SHOWPLAN on the query yet?

Comment: I you were right about NodeID being joined to an InterfaceID. I believe InterfaceID should be changed to NodeID. However, the query still does not finish. I apparently do not have permission to run SHOWPLAN, so I am in the process of getting permission to do so.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of notes:

1. The INNER JOIN operator is associative, so get rid of those parenthesis in the FROM clause and let the optimizer figure out the best join order.
2. You may have an *implied cursor* from the *getdate()* function being called for every row. Store the value in a local variable and compare to that.

The resulting SQL should look like this:

```
DECLARE @Date as datetime = getdate() - 30;

SELECT  TOP 10000
Nodes.Caption                              AS NodeName,
NetflowApplicationSummary.AppName          AS Application_Name,
SUM(NetflowApplicationSummary.TotalBytes)  AS SUM_of_Bytes_Transferred,
AVG(Case OutBandwidth
    When 0 Then 0
    Else (NetflowApplicationSummary.TotalBytes/OutBandwidth) * 100
End)                                       AS TEST_PERCENT

FROM NetflowApplicationSummary 
  INNER JOIN Nodes            ON NetflowApplicationSummary.NodeID = Nodes.NodeID 
  INNER JOIN InterfaceTraffic ON Nodes.NodeID = InterfaceTraffic.InterfaceID 
  INNER JOIN Interfaces       ON Nodes.NodeID = Interfaces.NodeID

WHERE InterfaceTraffic.DateTime > @Date 
  AND Nodes.WANCircuit          = 1

GROUP BY Nodes.Caption, NetflowApplicationSummary.AppName
```

Also, make sure you have an index on table *InterfaceTraffic* with a leading field of *DateTime*. If this doesn't exist you may need to pay the penalty of a first time creation of it.

If this doesn't help, then you may need to post the execution plan where it can be inspected.

Out of interest, also perform a *count(*) on all four tables and post that result, just so members here can make their own assessment of how *big* your database really is. It is amazing how many non-technical people still think a 1 or 10 GB database is huge, while I run that easily on my workstation!

Comment: I've been running your resulting SQL for the past 5 minutes or so. I'll update you if it works. I also ran count on each database with the following results: NetflowApplicationSummary = 50671011, Nodes = 898, InterfaceTraffic = 18000166, and Interfaces = 3938. If you total all of these up you get 68,676,013. I have no idea if that's actually huge or not.